# what difference between native php Exception and error with that text returned?

Tags: php, exception

```
    PHP Error[2]: ftp_login(): Login authentication failed
        in file /mnt/2vertex/Repos/gold/protected/components/data-adapters/FtpDataAdapter.php at line 37
    #0 /mnt/2vertex/Repos/gol/protected/components/data-adapters/FtpDataAdapter.php(37): ftp_login()
....
....
.... some stack info
```

is that an Exception or this is an error ? And really i cant catch it in my php code. with try catch(Exception $e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error but not native php. This is exception from Your code, ftp_login() - function where You get Your error. If You use some framework thay can have error handlers so that why You can't find error text in that place.

Comment: how i can find an Exception class name what i need to catch ? When i use phpunit and testing that class i can catch (Exception $e), but when my app in action (it's Yii framework console app) it cant be catched with Exception $e.

Comment: It can't be caught because it is not an exception, it is a warning.  If this is not code you wrote and you're looking for an easy workaround, you can use @ in front of the ftp_login() function.  If the code was written well at all, it should be using the return value from the function to branch.  There are more complicated things you do like using set_error_handler to catch warnings, and you could then throw an exception.

Comment: thank you very much, i found a code where that string is getting output. it's really not a native php warning or error. it's string after ErrorHandler function. thank you very much to @YamahaSY. to gview please don't recommend to use '@' before php functions, to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is actually a warning that is being thrown:  see http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-login.php